# Filter data from intermediate table with AND link

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-entities, model-associations

i'have following scenario:

Tables and Columns (Database Type: Microsoft Sql Server 2005):

### Table: Entries

- EntryID
- ... *other unimportant columns*

### Table: Attributes

- AttributeID

### Table: EntryAttributes

- EntryID [Releation To: Entries->EntryID]
- AttributeID [Releation To: Attributes->AttributeID]

So, how can i select only the Entries how contains multiple attributes like the following SQL statement (The statement doesn't work with the **AND** link):

```
SELECT *
FROM  [Entries] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [EntryAttributes] AS [t1] ON [t0].[EntryID] = [t1].[EntryID]
WHERE ([t1].[AttributeID] = 1) AND ([t1].[AttributeID] = 1)
```

How do i build the correct SQL statement? I'm sure, there's already a solution somewhere, but i don't know which keywords i should use to search for that problem.

I using 'Linq to Entites', so maybe there's a simple Linq expression for that.

Thanks for reading my post!

Best regards!

Comment: You have `WHERE ([t1].[AttributeID] = 1) AND ([t1].[AttributeID] = 1)` is that an error? Also is an SQL answer any good to you or do you need a Linq answer?

Comment: hi, i would test my statement in a clear SQL, but finally i need a Linq (to Entities) solution.
Ofcourse, the 'where' part is only 'pseudo code' and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this scenario is to join for each [AttributeID] which i would select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  [Entries] AS [t0] 
INNER JOIN [EntryAttributes] AS [t1] ON [t0].[EntryID] = [t1].[EntryID] 
INNER JOIN [EntryAttributes] AS [t2] ON [t0].[EntryID] = [t2].[EntryID] 
WHERE ([t1].[AttributeID] = 1) AND ([t2].[AttributeID] = 2)
```